# Facebook app warns about security certificate when it didn't before

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

An app I connect with via Facebook is now asking me about a security certificate. I don't know what that is or what to do with it.

In my example the app is DoubleDowns Casino. I have no problems with other apps on Facebook and had previously accessed it for a long time with no problem. It's only now showing this error message.

Answer (score 2):

These warning messages will appear if the connecting app's server has an expired security certificate.

It's a heads up to you to be wary just in case since the information isn't on a secured transmission. Nothing wrong on your account. And this may happen to games or apps you've used in the past with no problem because their certificate was still valid.

These things also sort themselves out quick enough when the app creators are aware of it and renew their security certificate.